# MVVM Validation on Server

Tags: mvvm

I have one question about the MVVM-Programming model.
Usually Validation is done in Model and/or ViewModel.
(Sometimes Validation has to be done in ViewModel, if the Validation involves multiple Model-objects, and other reasons maybe)

The Validation in the Model can be done on Server of Course, but what about Validation in ViewModel?

What is the usual practice for this? Instantiate a ViewModel on Server-Side?

EDIT:

Some additional info, as requested by auburg:

I dont have any concrete issue - it's just that it feels dangerous to accept any model which might be sent to my "Data Access Layer-Service", and just be able to do the model-validation (if there even is any! Some MVVM tutorials do all Validation in the ViewModel). If there is only Validation in the ViewModel layer, i wouldn't know if the Model is valid before i save it to the persistent data storage.

So - what would be best practice to do the full Validation on Server as well? Only do the Validation in Model?

Comment: What do you mean by 'Instantiate a ViewModel on Server-Side?' - are you referring to MVC rather than MVVM ?

Comment: I am referring to MVVM, but i have a Server/Client application in mind, where the Model is saved by some Servicecall to the web.

Comment: Can you edit your question and provide some further detail on the architecture of your application   - and on some specific issue (if any) you are facing. Currently your question is too vague.

Comment: You do both.  Validation in the UI is useful to the user so they can ensure their input is valid prior to submitting.  Then you validate it again on the server, because I'll be the one that submits invalid data using Postman or some other proxy, thus getting around your client side validation.

Comment: Yes, exactly...you want to do Validation on both sides....but...you do NOT want to replicate the Code to do so....how would i not replicate the Code if ist in my ViewModel (the "View" term indicates this shouldnt be used on Server)